# Why do the eyes of this cat have different colours when viewed from different angles?

Tags: eyes, optics, iris

Why do the eyes of this cat have different colours when viewed from different angles?

[image: Cat looking straight]

Both of the eyes of this cat appear yellow when looking straight at the camera.

[image: Cat looking at an angle]

However, when the cat looks at an angle to the camera one eye appears green. Unfortunately, the cat is not mine and I don't have many more pictures of it.

I have also noticed that my own eye which appears dark brown from straight on, looks lighter when viewed from an angle.

Why does this happen? Is there a special property of the iris that lends itself to such behaviour? In [this](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=916#:%7E:text=hit%20your%20eyes%20from%20different,will%20also%20seem%20to%20change.) website, it is mentioned that the colour of the iris varies with the angle at which it is viewed but no explanation is given.